# Textarea new line for sending an email using php

Tags: php, email, textarea, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer for sending mail and I have textarea for the body of mail.So when I write text I need to new line but when I new line it dose not work when the text rich to the mail, it still show only one line.
I have the PHP code as below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');        
    $mail  = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()" 
    $body = str_replace ('<br>' , '\r\n', $_POST['about']); // $_POST['about'] is the value text take from the body text area of mail
    //$body = $_POST['about'];
    $from  = $_POST['from'];    
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,$from);     
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from);       
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,$from);

    $address = $_POST['email'];
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $address);      
    $mail->Subject  = $_POST['subject'];

    $mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test     
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);      
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message envoy&eacute;!";
    }
}   
?>
```

Anyone help me to fix this please, thanks.

Comment: `$mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";` — I **strongly** recommend actually having a plain text alternative instead of an instruction to change email software. Your email is unlikely to be important enough for people to change email client to read it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out PHP's nl2br() function. I believe this is what you are looking for:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
$body = str_replace ('\r\n' , '<br>' , $_POST['about']);
```

`\r\n` should be replace with `<br>`

Comment: in this form the answer is not very useful. consider adding more explanation for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use,

```
$body = nl2br ($_POST['about']);
```

And ofcourse you are saving this to mysql database, so for that use,

```
$body = mysql_real_escape_string ( nl2br ($_POST['about']) );
```

Here note that, `$body = nl2br ( mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['about']) );` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why make this harder than it needs to be?

```
//here is the pull from the form
$your_form_text = $_POST['your_form_text'];

 //line 1 fixes the line breaks - line 2 the slashes
$your_form_text = nl2br($your_form_text);
$your_form_text = stripslashes($your_form_text);

//email away
$message = "Comments: $your_form_text";
mail("destination_email@whatever.com", "Website Form Submission", $message, $headers);
```

You will obviously need headers and likely have more fields, but this is your textarea.